# Tried animating one texture with alpha stacked on top of on another texture but not sure how to make both texture appear

Tags: shader-nodes

I'm trying to animate the symbols as in the picture by manipulating the transparency while stacking it with another texture. My problem arise when I can't seem to find a way to make the diffused texture of the sword to appear.

I'm not sure if anyone follow, I'm sorry my nodes kinda messy, I'm actually kinda new to Blender.
I plan to render using Eevee btw.

Or if anyone have a better, easier way to animate the appearance of the symbols, that would be great, I thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

Here's the project file if anyone interested to try to  solve the problem

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Do you want those symbols to gradually appear on the sword?

Comment: @JachymMichal Hi, sorry for the late reply. Yes, I would love to do that. Is it possible to do it while stacking it on top of another texture in the same material?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the kind of setup you can use to make font appear on an object: plug two *Diffuse* (and/or *Emission*) into a *Mix Shader* and use the mix *Factor* to switch from a shader to another. Here as there is a font that is supposed to be on transparent background, just plug its *Alpha* into a first *Mix Shader* where you plug 2 shaders: the one with the font color, the other with the background color.

[image]

So in your case you can do it this way, note that you don't have any alpha channel so just use the image itself as a mask in the factor of the *Mix Shader* (there may be simpler but it works):

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I tried doing this with no problem before adding the animation on the transparency. I guess the problem arise because of the animation, which is saddening for me.

Comment: what do you mean by adding the animation to the transparency? Just animate the Mix Shader factor value to switch from a shader to the other

Comment: you haven't packed any image in your blend file, please pack and share again: File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend

Comment: OMG... really sorry about that. Thanks for the comment. I have updated the file in the post. Please have a look, thank youuuuuu :D

Comment: ok I've edited, I hope it's clear, there must be a simpler way but it works anyway

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edit. Really appreciate it. I tried playing with factor on the mix shader too but the problem seems to be the alpha is actually burnt into the sword texture at frame 0 (It's like there are holes with the shape of the symbols there). I guess it's really can't be fixed.

Comment: actually you don't have any alpha channel for your rune image, so just plug the image output into the Mix Shader factor

Comment: I see. I guess I'll try replacing it with PNG and see how it goes. Thank you again. You are very kind!

Comment: make sure your PNG has an alpha channel in that case, but as I said, you can simply use your b&w image as a mask

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement @moonboots' detailed answer.
If you want the runes to gradually appear, why not just animate a gradient...

[image]

Comment: OMG! Thank you! This is definitely simpler. Definitely gonna try this.